# TypeError: . . . argument after ** must be a mapping, not a NoneType | Error from aiopokeapi data retrieval

Tags: python

I want to iterate through all of the move id's I have in a dict and call a function from [this](https://github.com/beastmatser/aiopokeapi) api to get their damage. pokemon is a pokemon class and moves is ['move id']['move name']. I have an issue when I'm running `moveData = await client.get_move(move)`. I get this TypeError `TypeError: aiopoke.objects.resources.moves.move.ContestComboSets() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType`. The function runs once, but crashes in the second time on the line in question.

This is a snippet of code I'm working with:

```
async def loadBaseDamage(pokemon, moves):
    async with aiopoke.AiopokeClient() as client:
        print("Displaying the damage of each move: ")
        for move in moves.keys():
            moveData = await client.get_move(move)
            print(pokemon.name, ":", move, "->", moveData.power)
```

This is the full error:

```
python3 old-main-aiopoke.py > output.txt
pikachu
charizard
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adrian/projects/poketype/prototype/old-main-aiopoke.py", line 125, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/adrian/projects/poketype/prototype/old-main-aiopoke.py", line 97, in main
    await loadBaseDamage(opponentOne, opponentOneMoves)
  File "/home/adrian/projects/poketype/prototype/old-main-aiopoke.py", line 69, in loadBaseDamage
    moveData = await client.get_move(move)
  File "/home/adrian/projects/virtualEnvironments/pokeTypeVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiopoke/utils/cache.py", line 27, in wrapper
    obj: U = await coro(client, name_or_id)
  File "/home/adrian/projects/virtualEnvironments/pokeTypeVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiopoke/aiopoke_client.py", line 193, in get_move
    return Move(**data)
  File "/home/adrian/projects/virtualEnvironments/pokeTypeVenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiopoke/objects/resources/moves/move.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.contest_combos = ContestComboSets(**contest_combos)
TypeError: aiopoke.objects.resources.moves.move.ContestComboSets() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

Current Output:

```
Enter pokemon 1: Enter pokemon 2: Displaying the damage of each move: 
pikachu : 5 -> 80
```

I've tried setting moveData.damage to a different variable beforehand and verified that `moveData = await client.get_move(move)` is the line that crashes my program.

Edit:
Here is the code in my main function and the modules I'm importing. Please let me know if more code is needed to help debug.

```
import asyncio
import aiopoke

    async def main():
        async with aiopoke.AiopokeClient() as client:
            # Available moves each opponent has
            opponentOneMoves = {}
            opponentTwoMoves = {}
            
            # Store the base damage of each move for both opponents
            baseOne = {}
            baseTwo = {}
            
    
            pokemonOne = input("Enter pokemon 1: ")
            pokemonTwo  = input("Enter pokemon 2: ")
            pokemonOne = pokemonOne.lower()
            pokemonTwo = pokemonTwo.lower()
    
            opponentOne = await client.get_pokemon(pokemonOne)
            loadMoves(opponentOne.name, opponentOne.moves, opponentOneMoves)
    
            opponentTwo = await client.get_pokemon(pokemonTwo)
            loadMoves(opponentTwo.name, opponentTwo.moves, opponentTwoMoves)
    
            await loadBaseDamage(opponentOne, opponentOneMoves)
            await loadBaseDamage(opponentTwo, opponentTwoMoves)
    
    
            # Note: Make a min and max heap for each pokemon with respect to their opposing pokemon
            ## The idea is to make a min and max of moves that are most effective for each pokemon
            ## against the pokemon they're against.
            oneMin = [None] * len(opponentOneMoves)
            oneMax = [None] * len(opponentOneMoves)
            twoMin = [None] * len(opponentTwoMoves)
            twoMax = [None] * len(opponentTwoMoves)
    
    
            # Search moves' base damage | Make another dict with the id and the move's base damage?
            # Develop type chart matrix, function, and txt file to read from.
            # Search moves on type chart in comparison against opposing pokemon.
                # sort move effectiveness in a max and min heap for each pokemon. (2 min and 2 max)
            
            print("Pokemon 1: " + opponentOne.name)
            print("Pokemon 1 moves: ")
            dumpMoves(opponentOne.name, opponentOneMoves)
            print()
            
            print("Pokemon 2: " + opponentTwo.name)
            print("Pokemon 2 moves: ")
            dumpMoves(opponentTwo.name, opponentTwoMoves)        
        
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't include the code that is generating the error. Please read about how to create a [mcve].